# OData query in swagger ui

Tags: c#, odata, owin, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I was checking out the following tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2015/03/10/using-odata-query-syntax-with-web-api.aspx

And I was curious if there was support in swagger ui somehow to show the query parameters.

Essentially I wanted all calls tagged with [EnableQueryAttribute] attribute to have swagger ui for inputting query parameters and I don't want to add these parameters to the method call I still want them to be in the URL and pulled out for the Owin context.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The chosen answer is out of data. With .NET 5, use this instead:

```
class EnableQueryFiler : IOperationFilter
{
    static List<OpenApiParameter> s_Parameters = (new List<(string Name, string Description)>()
            {
                ( "$top", "The max number of records."),
                ( "$skip", "The number of records to skip."),
                ( "$filter", "A function that must evaluate to true for a record to be returned."),
                ( "$select", "Specifies a subset of properties to return. Use a comma separated list."),
                ( "$orderby", "Determines what values are used to order a collection of records."),
                ( "$expand", "Use to add related query data.")
            }).Select(pair => new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = pair.Name,
                Required = false,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema { Type = "String" },
                In = ParameterLocation.Query,
                Description = pair.Description,

            }).ToList();

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.Any(em => em is Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute))
        {

            operation.Parameters ??= new List<OpenApiParameter>();
            foreach (var item in s_Parameters)
                operation.Parameters.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

You will then need to register the filter:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.OperationFilter<EnableQueryFilter>();
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer was much easier than I was thinking. What I ended up doing is creating an IOperationFilter and looked for all Operations with a certain return type and added the Parameters to it.

```
class QueryParameterFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        void IOperationFilter.Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (apiDescription.ResponseDescription.ResponseType != null && apiDescription.ResponseDescription.ResponseType.Name.Contains("PagedResult"))
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "$top", "The max number of records"},
                    { "$skip", "The number of records to skip"},
                    { "$filter", "A function that must evaluate to true for a record to be returned"},
                    { "$select", "Specifies a subset of properties to return"},
                    { "$orderby", "Determines what values are used to order a collection of records"}
                };
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
                foreach (var pair in parameters)
                {
                    operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
                    {
                        name = pair.Key,
                        required = false,
                        type = "string",
                        @in = "query",
                        description = pair.Value
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

And then they can retrieved through the owin context.

```
var params = owinContext.Request.Query.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.FirstOrDefault());
```