# Swagger OData using Swashbucke for "hybrid" C# WebApi services

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I am building a WebApi2 service using C#. It's a resource based service following a RESTful(ish) approach. The resource will be available through an API and exposed via a web page in a grid, where these is a level of sorting, paging and filtering of the resource required.

In order to avoid re-inventing the wheel I have leaned on oData query parameters and marked up the GET call with `[EnableQuery]`. This gives me the sorting, paging and filtering capabilities that I am after with minimal code and it works beautifully (sample implementation below).

However, I am now trying to wire in [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to document my API. Since my service is not a pure OData Service, Swashbuckle.OData does not recognize it and I do not get the (OData) query parameters added in to the documentation, I just get the plain service interface.

I was starting down the rabbit hole of debugging through [Swashbuckle.OData](https://github.com/rbeauchamp/Swashbuckle.OData)  but then thought I would rather ask first and hopefully save some time. From a cursory look at the code it handles OData and WebApi processing separately and then merges the resulting documents together. My service is a hybrid of the two and falls in to the WebApi category.

I have a work around with an `OperationFilter` for Swashbuckle (see code below, [modified from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351293/odata-query-in-swagger-ui)), but it would be good to get this out of the box with Swashbuckle.OData - am I missing a trick?

**--------- API sample ----------**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<MyResource>))]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<MyResource> GetMyResources()
{
     return repository.MyResources.AsQueryable();
}
```

**----- Work around ------**

```
 public class ODataParameterFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (apiDescription.ResponseDescription.ResponseType != null && apiDescription.ResponseDescription.ResponseType.Name.ToLower().Contains("queryable"))
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "$top", "The max number of records. (e.g. $top=10)"},
                    { "$skip", "The number of records to skip. (e.g. $skip=5)"},
                    { "$filter", "A function that must evaluate to true for a record to be returned. (e.g. $filter=CustomerName eq 'bob')"},
                    { "$select", "Specifies a subset of properties to return. (e.g. $select=Name)"},
                    { "$orderby", "Determines what values are used to order a collection of records. (e.g. $orderby=Address1_Country,Address1_City desc)"}
                };
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
                foreach (var pair in parameters)
                {
                    operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
                    {
                        name = pair.Key,
                        required = false,
                        type = "string",
                        @in = "query",
                        description = pair.Value
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

-**------ My SwaggerConfig.cs -------**

```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
        .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {                
             c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My Service");
             c.CustomProvider(defaultProvider => new ODataSwaggerProvider(defaultProvider, c));
        })
```

...

Comment: So you want Swagger.OData to render out your service uses some OData properties, but you don't want to make your service an OData service... You might need to elaborate a bit more on this. My question to you is simply why? You can have OData and other Rest services in the same site, you can even have non OData actions on your OData controllers if you wish. Then the Swagger docs do just work out of the box.